# Evaluating an integral of a function $a:\mathbb{N}\to [0,\infty)$ with respect to certain measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Let $(p_n)$ be a sequence of positive reals for $n\ge 0$. For any $N\subset \mathbb{N}$, define $\mu(N)=\sum_{n\in N} p_n$, with the convention that $\sum_{n\in \emptyset} p_n=0$. Then $\mu$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$). Now suppose that $a:\mathbb{N} \to [0,\infty)$. What is $\int_{\mathbb{N}} a\, d\mu$?

So basically I see that $a$ is a measurable function, so that the integral is well defined (though it may be $\infty$). Setting $A_n=\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$ by monotone convergence theorem we have

$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}} a \, d\mu = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{A_n} a\, d\mu
$$

But then what does this equal to? If domain of $a$ was, for instance, set of real numbers then I might proceed by saying that above integral is Riemann integrable etc, but in this case I'm really confused as to what this integral actually means.

Comment: $$\sum_n a(n)\cdot \mu(\{n\}) = \sum_n a(n) p_n$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I 'think' that is a true, but how do you reason it rigourously? I see that for any simple function on $A_n$ which is pointwisely smaller than $a$ has a supremum (of integral) $\sum_n a(n) p_n$, but do you think its enough to just say this?

Comment: Well, $\chi_{A_n}\cdot a$ is a simple function, namely $$\chi_{A_n}\cdot a = \sum_{k=0}^n a(k)\cdot \chi_{\{k\}}.$$ So by definition $$\int_{A_n} a\,d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{N}} \chi_{A_n}\cdot A\,d\mu = \sum_{k=0}^n a(k) \int_{\mathbb{N}} \chi_{\{k\}}\,d\mu = \sum_{k=0}^n a(k)\cdot \mu(\{k\}).$$

Comment: $N \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, I think?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, right. I was overcomplicating it a bit I guess. Thanks! And yes it should be $N\subset \mathbb{N}$, I just edited it.